# How to know which query(*) item is meet my need?

Tags: jquery, html, calabash

From query result can't see which one match with a textbox. My query result is as below, but now I need to find the textbox and input words in the text box and click the search button, from HTML. I can see the textbox's id is "forminput", but I can't use perfomAction to set text to the text box. How coudl I click the button? Which tag should I use?

(For html see by view source in [this web](http://m.youdao.com)

I have the following questions:

1. I want to enter text into the textbox, but I don't know which query item is the textbox.
2. How to input text to the box?
3. Which item is the button?
4. How to click the button to start searching?

This is query* result of the web:

```
 [ 0] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 142.0,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 284,
                   "y" => 0,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{b2da1390 V.E..... R.....I. 0,0-240,284}"
    },
    [ 1] {
                        "id" => "action_bar_overlay_layout",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 142.0,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 284,
                   "y" => 0,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout{b2dfed00 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-240,284 #1020313 android:id/action_bar_overlay_layout}"
    },
    [ 2] {
                        "id" => "content",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.FrameLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 169.5,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 229,
                   "y" => 55,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{b2da5930 V.E..... ......I. 0,55-240,284 #1020002 android:id/content}"
    },
    [ 3] {
                        "id" => "container",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.FrameLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 169.5,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 229,
                   "y" => 55,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.FrameLayout{b2df76d0 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,229 #7f05003c app:id/container}"
    },
    [ 4] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 169.5,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 229,
                   "y" => 55,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "android.support.v4.app.NoSaveStateFrameLayout{b2e2c3b8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,229}"
    },
    [ 5] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 169.5,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 229,
                   "y" => 55,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b2df86d8 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,229}"
    },
    [ 6] {
                        "id" => "mywebview",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => "Web View",
                     "class" => "android.webkit.WebView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 169.5,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 229,
                   "y" => 55,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "android.webkit.WebView{b2dbdd18 VFEDHVC. .F....I. 0,0-240,229 #7f05003d app:id/mywebview}"
    },
    [ 7] {
                        "id" => "action_bar_container",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 36,
                   "y" => 19,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarContainer{b2dab088 V.ED.... ......I. 0,19-240,55 #1020314 android:id/action_bar_container}"
    },
    [ 8] {
                        "id" => "action_bar",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 120.0,
              "height" => 36,
                   "y" => 19,
               "width" => 240,
                   "x" => 0
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView{b2d98560 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-240,36 #1020315 android:id/action_bar}"
    },
    [ 9] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => false,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 66.5,
              "height" => 36,
                   "y" => 19,
               "width" => 119,
                   "x" => 7
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b2dab638 V.....C. ......I. 7,0-126,36}"
    },
    [10] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 22.0,
              "height" => 36,
                   "y" => 19,
               "width" => 30,
                   "x" => 7
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$HomeView{b2de3f00 V.E..... ......I. 0,0-30,36}"
    },
    [11] {
                        "id" => "home",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.ImageView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 22.0,
              "height" => 24,
                   "y" => 25,
               "width" => 24,
                   "x" => 10
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.ImageView{b2e14210 V.ED.... ......I. 3,6-27,30 #102002c android:id/home}"
    },
    [12] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.LinearLayout",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 36.5,
            "center_x" => 81.5,
              "height" => 19,
                   "y" => 27,
               "width" => 89,
                   "x" => 37
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.LinearLayout{b2dda508 V.E..... ......I. 30,8-119,27}"
    },
    [13] {
                        "id" => "action_bar_title",
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "android.widget.TextView",
                      "text" => "TestWebView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 36.5,
            "center_x" => 78.5,
              "height" => 19,
                   "y" => 27,
               "width" => 83,
                   "x" => 37
        },
               "description" => "android.widget.TextView{b2dbc4b8 V.ED.... ......I. 0,0-83,19 #1020265 android:id/action_bar_title}"
    },
    [14] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => nil,
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 219.0,
              "height" => 36,
                   "y" => 19,
               "width" => 42,
                   "x" => 198
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuView{b2df5188 V.ED.... ......I. 198,0-240,36}"
    },
    [15] {
                        "id" => nil,
                   "enabled" => true,
        "contentDescription" => "More options",
                     "class" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton",
                      "rect" => {
            "center_y" => 37.0,
            "center_x" => 219.0,
              "height" => 36,
                   "y" => 19,
               "width" => 42,
                   "x" => 198
        },
               "description" => "com.android.internal.view.menu.ActionMenuPresenter$OverflowMenuButton{b2de1788 VFED..C. ......I. 0,0-42,36}"
    }
]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Thank you for updating my question. But one answer is lost .

Answer (score 1):

**First of all, if you're working with WebViews you should use `query "webView css:'*'"` instead of simple `query "*"` to get all elements.**

---

> I want to enter text into the textbox, but I don't know which query item is the text box.

You'll find all textboxes with `query "webView css:'input'"`. And then find the required one within them, e.g. with `query "webView css:'input[name=\"q\"]'"`.

---

> How to input text to the box?

Using `set_text` method, e.g. `set_text "webView css:'input[name=\"q\"]'", "text"`.

---

> Which item is the button?

It depends on web page implementation. You should look into output output of `query "webView css:'*'"`. Usually elements are listed in that output in the same order as they appear on webpage. So if a button goes after input field, it will go after it in `query` output.

---

> How to click the button to start searching?

With `touch` command, e.g. `touch "webView css:'input[class=\"btn\"]'"`.

---

[Here is a short info](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android/wiki/06-webview-support) on working with WebViews from calabash-android documentation.

Comment: Thank you Dmitry, I will try you methods .

Comment: Then I enter "test" into input field with name "q"

Comment: Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into input field with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, css|
      set_text "webView css:'input[name=\"q\"]'", "text"
end

Comment: Then I press the button with class "btn"

Comment: Then /^I press the button with id "([^\"]*)"$/ do | css|
   
    touch "webView css:'input[class=\"btn\"]'"
  
   end

Comment: result is : 2 undefined . Seems they are not execute .

Comment: @yaner, it looks like you define steps as `... with id ...` however in scenarios `... with name ...` are used.

Comment: Moreover, if you want to parametrise steps, then in step definitions to get value parameters should go as `"#{parameter_name}"`. For instance, `Then /^I enter "([^\"]*)" into input field with name "([^\"]*)"$/ do |text, css_name| set_text "webView css:'input[name=\"#{css_name}\"]'", "#{text}" end`

Answer (score 1):

If you have hint text in the input fields, you might also be able to solve this by using a simple "tap 'hint text'" command.

For example if your username has the hint text "username". Then you could try "tap 'username'".

And for the button you can use the same, if it has a text. For example "Login" then do "tap 'Login'".

I know it works on iOS, but I am not sure if it works for HTML testing.